# What happens when malloc doesn't find the memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, null-pointer

What happens when `malloc` returns the `NULL` value to the pointer?
When this if statement gets executed

```
if (ptr == NULL) { 

    printf("Memory not allocated.\n"); 

    exit(0); 

}
```

And we come out of the program. Then after that what makes `malloc` to find memory for the same code?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when `malloc` returns the `NULL` value to the pointer?

According to [the manual page for `malloc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), it can return `NULL` in two cases:

1. The requested size was `0`.
2. The allocator isn't able to find enough free memory to satisfy the request.

Assuming #2 happens, there can be different reasons behind it:

1. Your system really ran out of memory. This could either be caused by your program or by some other program(s) running on the same machine.
2. Your process exceeded the [resource limits](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) set for its memory (see `RLIMIT_AS` and `RLIMIT_DATA`).
3. Your program is being traced/debugged by something/someone that is controlling allocations and returning `NULL` for testing purposes.

> Then after that what makes `malloc` to find memory for the same code?

Using the same numbering as above, `malloc` will find memory on the next run of your program if:

1. The program is restarted after the system is able to release the needed amount of memory.
2. The program is restarted under different `rlimit` memory limits.
3. The program is restarted outside the testing/debugging context.

Comment: C17 has an update in regard to 0: "... If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned to indicate an error, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."